# DataBinding to a List in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I've got a Grid which contains a TextBlock. The Grid's DataContext is of type `List<MyClass>`, and I'd like to bind the TextBlock.Text property to the MyClass.MyProperty property of first element in the List. I tried something like:

```
<Grid x:Name="RootLayout">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].MyProperty}" />
</Grid>
```

But of course, that did not work. What's the right way of doing this?

**Edit:**

I'm going to try and make my explanation more clear. I've got multiple elements in the grid, each of which binds to a different item in the list. The items are laid out in a customized manner which cannot be accomplished by a GridView or ListBox. One of the items in the Grid is the TextBlock, and I'd like to bind its Text property to a property of the first element in the list. Once I know how to do that, I can extend that knowledge to add bindings to the rest of the elements in the grid.

**Edit 2:**

Turns out, my code works just fine in Silverlight. My project is actually a WinRT project, but I figured I'd get quicker answers if I tagged it as Silverlight, since databinding is supposed to work the same. I'm assuming this is a bug in WinRT, so I'll just have to find a workaround for it :(

Comment: First question: Do you want to show all items or only the first? If you want all items a List or DataGrid or other container that supports multiple items (e.g. via an ItemsSource property) is required.

Comment: @HiTech Magic I need all items. However, the layout I require doesn't exactly work well with ListBox or DataGrid. I'm also adding animation for each individual item in the Grid, so that further complicates things.

Comment: Reading through again a few more times, I'm just not sure we're getting a clear picture of what you're going for here.  You need all of the items in the list but you only want the TextBox to bind to a property on the first item in the list - do other controls in the grid bind to other items in the list?  Do you have a control that you want to use to iterate the list and have the TextBox display MyProperty for each item in the list as you go through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get why you want to do this, but you could create a property that returns what you want from the item in the list like so:

```
public string MyBindingProperty
{
    get { return MyList != null && MyList.Count > 0 ? MyList[0].MyProperty : "Error Text"; }
}
```

Then you'd bind to `MyBindingProperty`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyBindingProperty}" />
```

EDIT

I was wrong in saying you can't get at the items in the List - my bad.  Your binding should look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].MyProperty}" />
```

If you need me I'll be in the corner enjoying my humble pie.

Comment: That'd defeat the purpose of using the DataContext :) Either way, the TextBlock is not the only element that relies on the List as it's data context, so it'd be really tedious to have to define extra properties for each binding

Comment: I'm not following you when you say it would defeat the purpose?

Comment: The data context is supposed to act as the data source; adding proxy properties just adds extra overhead that I can avoid by modifying my data context from a list to a container that holds the list. However, I'd like to see if I can accomplish this without modifying my codebehing.

Comment: I understand how `DataContext` works.  My point is that I don't know whether you can do what you're wanting to do any other way - TextBox.Text is a string property, so unless I'm wrong (please correct me) it's going to look to be bound to a string, or it will call `ToString()` on whatever you bind to - in this case getting you "System.Collections.Generic.List<T>" or something similar, and I don't believe there's any way when defining the binding to coax it into iterating the list or getting at a specific entry in the list, hence a wrapper property to get what you want.  Or use a `ListBox`.

Comment: MyProperty is of type string. Since I'm not just binding to a property of an element in the list, I wouldn't get "System.Collections.Generic.List<T>"

Comment: Whatever you got out of it, it's not likely to be what you wanted - my point here is that the answer to "What's the right way of doing this?" is not "Bind a grid to a List<T>" - the grid won't iterate over the list and it won't give you access to the items in the list - you have to use a control meant for that type of data, like a `ListBox` or a `DataGrid` - or, write a wrapper class to use as a presenter and bind to and use properties in the wrapper class to get at the items in the list and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of `SL` but I think your are using the wrong `Grid` object; try with `DataGrid` in this way:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="targetDataGrid">
     <data:DataGrid.Columns>
         <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="MyProperty" 
             Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" />
     </data:DataGrid.Columns>
 </data:DataGrid>
```

also see here for more details: [Defining Silverlight DataGrid Columns at Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx)

Edit: then go this way:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
</Grid>
```

found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=VS.95%29.aspx scroll donw the article...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use DataGrid or ListBox due to other restrictions that I omitted to keep the example concise.